# Can I browse Core Data persistent storage on a simulator device using Xcode?

Tags: ios, core-data

Is there any way to browse/see the Downloaded data when using core data to see what is actually ending up in my persistent storage?

Comment: yes you can see that when you set up persistent storage at that time you need to give path those path you can see your  persistent storage file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are up to use 3rd party programs, I strongly recommend SlimPholders, it will have a list of your latests builds and you can easily open the finder folder of the last build you made! And from there just use a program like Sqlitebrowser to open the DB. Thats what I use and works perfectly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get file url of your coreData database:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Then you can use Finder to open the file directory.

Core Data is  usually based on SQLite, if so you can open the database with [SQLitePro for SQLite.](https://www.sqlitepro.com/)